# regex: return ini section as string

Tags: regex, ini

Using regex, (I am using Autohotkey, which is PCRE) how can I match the section of an ini file?  I don't need to get the individual keys - just the section block.

I've come up with this, which seems to match as long as there is a section after the sought section, but if it is the last section, it fails.

`iniregex := "ms)(?<=^\[keys\]).*(?=^\[)"`

Example, I want to get the entire contents of the section, `[keys]`, whilst excluding the comments and ignoring the empty lines (it should capture `test=2`, however, but exclude the comment on that line:

```
[settings]
settings=0
;settings=1

[keys]
test=0
;test=1
test=2 ;comment
test=3
[nextsection]
this section has an empty and should be caught.

there is an empty line after this line, and it should be caught, too.

    eof
```

[I found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561508/match-ini-section-blocks?rq=1), but I'm not sure where to put the sought section name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this with a single regexp.

What you can do is using this regexp based on your quote to extract the `[keys]` section without including the `[keys]` tag:

```
/^(?<=\[keys\]\r\n)(?:(?!^\[).)*(?=\r\n)/ms
```

Afterwards you can use [this regexp](http://regexr.com?345k7) for the extracted section to exclude comments/blank lines:

```
/^[^;\s][^;\r\n]*/gm
```

Comment: The first regex gets me the section like I want, but the second doesn't seem to exclude the comments.

Comment: in the first regex, how can that be made to exclude the newlines after `[keys]` and before the next `[` ?

Comment: @BGM Do you want to exclude the whole `[keys]` string with the following newline? And what kind of newlines do you have? `\r\n`, `\n`, `\r`?

Comment: Yes, I want to exclude the entire [keys] line, as well as the next section tag if there is one.  But I want to capture *everything* in between the tagged lines.

Comment: @BGM You didn't say what kind of newlines you have.

Comment: you mean, whether I am using Windows or Linux newlines?  I am using Windows - which is `\r\n`.  Sorry - my brain skipped your question (in plain sight...).

Comment: @BGM I modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: That's it!  You got it before I did. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

From your linked question, you would put the sought section name here:

`(?ms)^\[keys](?:(?!^\[[^]\r\n]+]).)*`

I don't think you'll be able to strip the comments out in the same regex as the capture, however. You'll have to do that in a secondary step.

Your regex fails if there is no section after `[keys]` because you need to put a "0 or more" type quantifier for the next section. Something like:

`iniregex := "ms)(?<=^\[keys\]).*(?:(?=^\[))?"`

Comment: I think if you just make the trailing lookahead optional like that, you'll end up capturing the whole rest of the file and not stopping at the next section.  Maybe `(?=^\[|\z)` instead?